# apt update throws signature error in Ubuntu 20.04 container on arm

Tags: 20.04, docker, raspberrypi, gnupg, arm

I am trying to build Raspberry Pi docker images but I am always having the same error, similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59139453/repository-is-not-signed-in-docker-build), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56563592/error-occurring-during-the-signature-verification-of-apt-get-update) and [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1059346/apt-get-update-not-working-signing-verification-errors).

While running the command `apt update` as root in a `arm32v7/ubuntu:20.04` (or just `ubuntu:latest`), I get the following output:

```
root@273d63597ce6:/# apt update
Get:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal InRelease [265 kB]
Get:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates InRelease [111 kB]
Get:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports InRelease [98.3 kB]
Get:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security InRelease [107 kB]
Err:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal InRelease
  At least one invalid signature was encountered.
Err:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates InRelease
  At least one invalid signature was encountered.
Err:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports InRelease
  At least one invalid signature was encountered.
Err:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security InRelease
  At least one invalid signature was encountered.
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I have tried the suggested solutions of cleaning apt, cleaning docker and removing/recreating `/var/lib/apt/lists` without success. The SD card is 32G and the OS is a fresh install. `df` shows 26G free.

Some more information:

- This is happening on a fresh install of 2020-05-27-raspios-buster-lite-armhf on a raspberry pi 4 B
- The same error happens on another Raspberry Pi 4 B running HypriotOS
- The same command in the same image works fine on a raspberry pi 3 B that has Arch linux installed
- The error does not happen if I use an older version of ubuntu (`ubuntu:18.04`, `16.04`, `14.04`)

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! I don't think this is how you prune an image, but I tried both `docker image rm ubuntu:20.04` and `docker system prune -a -f` and it did not fix the problem.

Comment: For me, I had run out of disk space in docker4mac and just needed to run `docker system prune`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The root cause of the problem [is in libseccomp](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/40734). The newer version fixes the problem, but it is not yet available in Debian's stable repos. There are two way to fix this problem:

**Method 1**

Start the container with `--privileged`. This bypasses docker's security measures, so it is not recommended. Or with `--security-opt seccomp:unconfined` as a little more secure.
`docker run -it --security-opt seccomp:unconfined ubuntu:latest`

**Method 2**

Upgrade libseccomp manually on the host system. Dowload version from unstable repos (I tested with 2.4.3-1) [here](https://packages.debian.org/sid/libseccomp2).

Install the new version:

`sudo dpkg -i libseccomp2_2.4.3-1+b1_armhf.deb`

Note: The above methods solved the problems for systems based on Raspbian. The error was also happening on a Ubuntu 20.04 aarch64 system, for which @NeonLines' answer was able to help.

Comment: The "Method 2" description in this answer is helpful, although it is not immediately clear whether I need to perform the libseccomp2 upgrade on the Raspberry Pi host system or in the docker image: It needs to be upgraded in the RaspiOS host system. The forced purge of the old version is unnecessary, an upgrade performed by dpkg -i is successful without first uninstalling the old version.

Comment: Good to know ! I updated the answer to reflects this.

Comment: Thanks, method 2 worked for me on rpi3.

Comment: Just upgraded it to 2.4.4-1~bpo10+1 and it worked. I am on Raspberry Pi OS (debian) Buster. Thanks for the answer. https://packages.debian.org/buster-backports/libseccomp2

Comment: amazing, just ran this on the host rpi without restarting the container `cd /tmp;wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libs/libseccomp/libseccomp2_2.5.1-1_armhf.deb;sudo dpkg -i libseccomp2_2.5.1-1_armhf.deb`

Answer (score 3):

> At least one invalid signature was encountered

The error suggests that one of the files in `/var/lib/apt/lists` consist at least one invalid/corrupted signature (could be the result of `apt-key` misuse or something else).

Try to run Apt update with the debug messages:

```
apt-get -oDebug::pkgAcquire::Worker=1 update
```

which should point you to the corrupted file, e.g.

> 0% [Working] <- gpgv:400%20URI%20Failure%0aMessage:%20At%20least%20one%20invalid%20signature%20was%20encountered.%0aURI:%20gpgv:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/CorruptedFile_InRelease

Edit the file, find and remove the corrupted parts, or remove the whole file, so it can be recreated.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to docker version 19.03.12 has resolved this issue for me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! That is the version that I am currently running. From what version did you upgrade ? What is your build number from `docker --version` ?

Comment: It is running `build 48a6621` Edit: Also this is running 20.04.1 however I have confirmed this is working with 20.04 as well.

Comment: Also during the upgrade I followed the steps at [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) mainly the regrabbing of the key as well as removing all previous installed packages. I believe docker-ce has now moved to docker-ce-cli so this also could be playing a part if you still have the old version of docker-ce installed or other packages

Comment: Reinstalling and fetching the key did not solve the problem. Are you really running on a raspberry pi ? And you are able to run apt update in a ubuntu focal docker container ? Also, if that is the case, how can you specify a 20.04.1 image ? It seems it does not exists for me

Comment: It seems like this solution did solve the problem for another machine that I had. Thanks !

Comment: On a Raspberry Pi, I have docker-ce and docker-ce-cli installed in version 5:19.03.12~3-0~raspbian-buster, and I am still seeing the exact problem described in the question when trying to work with an ubuntu:20.04 image. Sorry, but this answer does not help.

Answer (score 1):

TSpark's, HyperCreeks and ibster1st123s answers did work for me on a Rasbian 10 and the latest docker version from the official repositories. As NeonLines pointed out you have to install a recent version, since they don't suffer this problem.

> Most users set up Docker’s repositories and install from them, for
> ease of installation and upgrade tasks. This is the recommended
> approach, except for Raspbian. […] For Raspbian, installing using the
> repository is not yet supported. You must instead use the [convenience
> script](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/#install-using-the-convenience-script).
> – *docs.docker.com*

**tl;dr**

Get a recent docker version using the convenience script. You should check the link above though, there are some caveats.

```
curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh
sudo sh get-docker.sh
```