# arm used ubuntu:23.10, docker build faild, start container with --privileged ok

Tags: permissions, docker, arm

build image base `ubuntu:23.10` error

```
W: GPG error: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports mantic InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports mantic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports mantic-updates InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports mantic-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports mantic-backports InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports mantic-backports InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports mantic-security InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports mantic-security InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke 'rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:23.10
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt update \
    && apt-get -y update  \
    && apt-get -y upgrade \
    && rm -fr /root/.cache/pip/wheels/* \
    && rm -fr /tmp/* \
    && apt-get clean \
    && apt-get autoclean \
    && apt-get autoremove
```

used docker run a container,same error occurs.

I'm try run with --privileged option, it ok.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apt update throws signature error in Ubuntu 20.04 container on arm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263284/apt-update-throws-signature-error-in-ubuntu-20-04-container-on-arm)

Comment: thanks @karel, i‘ll try it.